# Expand/Collapse with Ant Typography

Tags: antd

Ant Design has a `Typography` library which is helpful in displaying text. One particularly helpful feature is the ability to "Expand" text. From the Ant documentation, you can display a paragraph as such:

[image]

Hitting "Expand" will produce the following:

[image]

The issue here, is that after you expand there is no option to "Collapse" the text back to what we had originally, which can be problematic. I have been looking through the `Typography` documentation [here](https://ant.design/components/typography/), but there is no mention of the ability to collapse. I was wondering if there was a way to achieve something like a "Collapse" using the Ant `Typography` library.

Another option that I have considered is the [react-text-collapse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-text-collapse) library, however I am not sure it is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like ant design doesn't have default option to collapse the typography paragraph. You can request for the feature at ant design github.

However you can achieve it with some state changes.
Here is the sample link

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-jepsen-4h7ek

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    expand: false,
    counter: 0
  };

  typoExpand = () => {
    this.setState({
      expand: true,
      counter: !this.state.expand
        ? this.state.counter + 0
        : this.state.counter + 1
    });
  };

  typoClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      expand: false,
      counter: !this.state.expand
        ? this.state.counter + 0
        : this.state.counter + 1
    });
  };

  renderParagraph() {
    return (
      <div key={this.state.counter}>
        <Paragraph
          ellipsis={{
            rows: 3,
            expandable: true,
            onExpand: this.typoExpand
          }}
        >
          Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined
          by Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a design language for background
          applications, is refined by Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a design
          language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team. Ant
          Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by
          Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a design language for background
          applications, is refined by Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a design
          language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team.
        </Paragraph>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderParagraph()}
        {this.state.expand && <a onClick={this.typoClose}>Close</a>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just add a state to the target `Typography`, for example:

```
const { Paragraph, Text } = Typography;

const App = () => {
  const [expandable, setExpandable] = useState(true);

  const toggle = () => setExpandable(p => !p);

  return (
//   v Style the container for your needs
    <div>
      <Paragraph ellipsis={{ rows: 3, expandable }}>
        Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by
        Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a design language for background applications,
        is refined by Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a design language for background
        applications, is refined by Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a design language
        for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a
        design language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team.
        Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by
        Ant UED Team.
      </Paragraph>

      <Text code onClick={toggle}>
        Expand
      </Text>
    </div>
  );
};
```

What's left is to style the container (which depends on you), like making a flexbox (antd got `Grid` implemented) so the `Expand` action will be "at the end" of the paragraph (and not a block as in the example).

[image: Edit Q-57964521-ExpandText]

Comment: This is actually not a good approach, because then once you click to Collapse it, you in fact are completely making the typography NOT expandable anymore, so you won't be able to Expand it again.